# How to move ip adresses to the end of line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, txtextcontrol

I have the data as follows in txt:

```
136.40.226.97|ubnt|ubnt|
138.197.81.94|listd|54e172662|
138.68.254.243|wordpress|wordpress|
139.162.55.12|public|public|
139.60.58.136|system|OkwKcECs8qJP2Z|
```

I want to convert it to this:

```
|ubnt|ubnt|136.40.226.97
|listd|54e172662|138.197.81.94
|wordpress|wordpress|138.68.254.243
|public|public|139.162.55.12
|system|OkwKcECs8qJP2Z|139.60.58.136
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *Find and Replace* window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> change *Search Mode* to *Regular expression* and set:

*Find what:* `(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(.*)`
*Replace with:* `(\2)(\1)`

This will find too groups: IP(1), rest of line(2), then Replace writes them in inverted order.